# .Net SQL Server queries from PowerShell

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell, t-sql

So I have this connection

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=Something ;Initial Catalog=Something ;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$query = "select MAX(ID) from [dbo].[Table];" 
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$NewID = $command.ExecuteScalar() 
$connection.Close()

echo $NewID
```

And it works fine and does the job. Say I want to `INSERT A ROW`. Do I need the last 3 lines possibly with another method in  `$command.method()`? In which line is the query actually executed?

Question 2: What method should I use if I want to get the whole result set to PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a query without a result (like an `INSERT`) you can use [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

```
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you want to to return non-scalar results, use [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Comment: So '$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)' does not do anything?

Comment: It creates the `SqlCommand` object that you use for adding parameters, executing SQL commands and returning the results. Have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
###...your code up to $NewID = ...

$rdr = $command.ExecuteReader(1)
#get-type $rdr

$dt = new-object system.data.datatable
$dt.load($rdr)

$dt | out-gridview
```

Comment: Your answer is not bad but maybe you should explain it.